# 401 UNAUTHORIZED if use IP instead of sharepoint sitename

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When I use sitename:port in URL, everything is OK and I can access sharepoint portal.

But When I use the IP instead of sitename, 401 UNAUTHORIZED error will be shown.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing I was looking for is Alternate Access Mappings.

Need to go to Central Admin > Application Management > Alternate Access Mappings > Edit Public URLs and add my full server name to Internet zone.

[This article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14609/cant-pass-authentication-to-browse-a-sharepoint-site/14611#14611) may also help.